# Does there exist any subsequence $(u_{n_k})$ converging strongly in $L^q(\mathbb{R})$, for any $1 \le q \le \infty$?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis

Fix a function $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, $\varphi \not\equiv 0$, and set $u_n(x) = \varphi(x + n)$. Let $1 \le p \le \infty$. Does there exist any subsequence $(u_{n_k})$ converging strongly in $L^q(\mathbb{R})$, for any $1 \le q \le \infty$?

Comment: This isn't a research level question and should be posted instead on http://math.stackexchange.com.  It will help to include some context for the problem and an explanation of what you have tried.

Comment: Well, 4 people apparently disagree with me, judging from upvotes, so I'll post the answer.

Comment: By the way, why do you define $p$ which is never used?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Since $\varphi$ is compactly supported we have $u_n \to 0$ pointwise.  Thus if any subsequence converges in $L^q$ the limit must be 0 (a.e.).  But by translation invariance $\|u_n\|_q = \|\varphi\|_q \ne 0$ for all $n$, so no subsequence can converge to 0 in $L^q$.